# How to Determine prerequisite creating setup exe in C# DotNet?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows

I am a new one in programming world.

Recently, I have created a windows desktop application program using **c# dotnetframework 4.0**. In which SQLite has been used as database, crystal reports, zip utility, encryption has also been  included.

It is a 32bit program. I has program this under windows 8 operating system with Visual Studio 2010.

I have created a setup exe file including prerequisite set as "Download Prerequisite from the same location as my application".
It has been successfully done and successfully installed and successfully working in other Windows 7 32bit OS, in Windows 7 64bit OS and also Windows 8 32bit as well as 64bit OS.

Now, the problem is, the software successfully install in every OS but not 100% successfully working, specially which is fresh new Windows Installed pc.

I could not figure it out why it is working perfectly in few pcs but not in every one's pc?

In failed pc, after installation when try to execute the program as right with or without administrator, no success. It shows in message box "**system.io.filenotfoundexception**" error.

```
Windows gives the following:

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\MxPrime\AppData\Local\Temp\WER27A0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\MxPrime\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4619.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\MxPrime\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4629.tmp.mdmp

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Please, help me? What are the requisites that are missing in the fresh new Windows Installed pc? If I have missed to add any prerequisite then how does it work in few pc? Puzzled!!!
Please Help me?

Thanks in advance.

Waiting for your kind geek help.

MD. NASIM

Answer (score 0):

`The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 redistributable package installs the .NET Framework runtime and associated files that are required to run and develop applications to target the .NET Framework 4.`

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17718

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException` means your program is trying to access a file at a location that doesn't exist, you need to determine what File it's trying to access and where.

Comment: Dear Spark, Thank you for the try. I have already include the mentioned Microsoft .NET Framework 4 re-distributable package from the given link. And if there is any file does not exist then how could it works fine on few pc as I mentioned above. staying at the same stage.

Comment: The exception could possibly be thrown as a result of trying to run the program without the correct runtime dependencies installed. Pretty sure most dependencies are installed as windows updates these days.

Answer (score 0):

As It is an application software including database "SQLite" in C# dotnetframework 4.0 Therefore it is required to create setup.exe with all of its prerequisites, such as dotnetframework 4.0.

But initially, I ignored to include prerequisite of SQLite database. As SQLite is a product of c++ so, when I include C++ runtime with it, all problem has been solved.

That's it.